# android image button

Tags: android, image, button

How can i create a button with no text and an image centered horizontally ? 
I don't want to use an ImageButton because I want to define a different backgound image

Answer (score 206, accepted):

You just use an ImageButton and make the background whatever you want and set the icon as the src.

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ImageButton01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/album_icon"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button" />
```

[image]

Comment: Please justify and descrive more about android:background!

Comment: @EmadAghayi src is the actual icon that will be used in the ImageButton; background is the shape of the original button, which is a rectangle by default. If you want to use only the image, you can omit it, or you can use other colors/shapes around the icon.

Answer (score 22):

just use a Button with android:drawableRight properties like this:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/btnNovaCompra" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_novaCompra"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/shoppingcart"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 13):

You can just set the onClick of an ImageView and also set it to be clickable, Or set the drawableBottom property of a regular button.

```
    ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
   iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the button :

1 - make the text empty

2 - set the background for it

+3 - you can use the selector to more useful and nice button

---

About the imagebutton you can set the image source and the background the same picture and it must be (*.png) when you do it you can make any design for the button

and for more beauty button use the selector //just Google it ;)