# ImageButton in Android with transparent background

Tags: android, imagebutton

I have follow this post to make ImageButton in android

[android image button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283444/android-image-button)

The image appears to the button but it has some background , my Image is a png image and I want the button to be transparent background

any one help please

Answer (score 80, accepted):

add this line to your ImageButton xml layout.

```
android:background="@null"
```

Comment: Wow, that simple... Thx!

Comment: But I'm setting the image in the background property itself!

Comment: If you want an image with a transparent background you can do it like this in the xml layout:
`android:background="@null"
android:src="@drawable/myimage"`

Answer (score 12):

Here's an alternative solution that worked for me:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

As Sunny said, add it to the ImageButtons' XML layout

Answer (score 1):

In your code use this:

```
ImageButton btn = new ImageButton(this);
btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_close);
btn.setBackgroundResource(0);
```

Comment: This worked for me, but another way that worked was: btn.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is any method to do that, but you can paint completely transparent .png file and use method setBackGroundResource() or in XML using this : android:background

Answer (score 0):

By this way you can set transparent background to ImageButton:

```
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/imagebutton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/<imageresourcename>"
android:background="@null"></ImageButton>
```