# ImageButton Not Showing transparency even it is in PNG Format

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I am creating an app which have an ImageButton in the Center. The problem is that I am not getting a transparent image inside the imagebutton even the image is in pure PNG format.

My Xml is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="switchmode.lteonly.lteonlyswitch.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/myimage"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

The output Layoutis as follows.

[image]

Any Idea how to resolve this??

Comment: that is the background with your image...remove it

Comment: Yes You are right. It is the background color. But How to make the background as transparent??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImageButton in Android with transparent background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195963/imagebutton-in-android-with-transparent-background)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add this in your `ImageButton` Layout

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: @DroidGenie always wc.

Answer (score 2):

add this to `ImageButton`

```
android:background="@null"
```

Answer (score 1):

1) I guess your png-file is not transparent. (Only because it's PNG it does not mean, the background is transparent). Check if it there is an alpha channel in the picture und there is no backgroundcolor in the image itself.

2) If this image is actually transparent try to add

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

to the ImageButton

Answer (score 1):

```
Add this to your imageButton
 android:background="#00000000"
```