# Full Screen ImageButton

Tags: android

I trying to create a full screen Imagebutton. But i kept getting grey border ard it.

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/StartButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"        
        android:src="@drawable/startscreen" />
```

I have try stretch the pic to full screen on eclipse but there still show a grey border around the picture.

I was wondering is that due to the resolution of my setting or the picture resolution. I am working on a galaxy note.

Comment: Use ImageView and set a onclicklistener. check this out -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283444/android-image-button

Answer (score 2):

this should remove the grey border

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/StartButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"        
        android:src="@drawable/startscreen" 
        android:background="#000000"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea of @Proxy32 is probably the best one. Alternatively don't use the `android:src` attribute but the `android:background`. You can also use a simple `Button` instead with the background set to your drawable and leave the text out.