# Difference between image button and button

Tags: android, button, imagebutton

What is the difference between `Button` and `ImageButton`, where if we use any image in button's background its also work like image button. So why we use image button?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Button extends TextView, allowing you to create clickable text with a background image.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

ImageButton extends Image view, which has more methods relevant to the manipulation of images.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html

Comment: To expand on this answer a bit more you in Button you can set the label and the background image.  For ImageButton you can set a foreground image and a background image.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283444/android-image-button/2283993#2283993