# Create arrow sign pointing 45 degrees in android

Tags: android, button, graphics, drawable

I would like to create a black arrow button that is facing 45 degrees. I have no idea how to go about this.

I want the arrow to look like the one found on this screen. https://cloud.google.com/developers/images/articles/developing-mobile-games-on-gcp/sample-q.png

Comment: Try to explain your problem better. If possible show a mockup of the arrow button

Comment: The arrow button should possible look like the one found on this screen https://cloud.google.com/developers/images/articles/developing-mobile-games-on-gcp/sample-q.png

Comment: This website provides you the android default icons, you can use them. Here is your button: http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-generic.html#source.type=clipart&source.space.trim=0&source.space.pad=0&source.clipart=res/clipart/icons/navigation_next_item.svg&size=24&padding=8&color=000,100&name=ic_navigation_next_item

Answer (score 0):

can you specify whats the purpose?
If you have an image of the arrow you want. you can create a Button, and place a background image for it see:   [See this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283444/android-image-button)

or if you want to create your own arrow, you can create a custom-view, by extending View class, and draw it yourself in onDraw() method, using canvas operations

in my opinion, if its somthing basic, take the first option