# How do you place an item behind another item in android?

Tags: android

I'd like to place an `ImageView` behind an `ImageButton`. What's the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Could I get a comment on the -1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the easiest way to do this is to wrap both the `ImageView` and `ImageButton` in a `FrameLayout`. eg:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/your_image" />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can overlap views in certain layouts (e.g. `FrameLayout`, `RelativeLayout`).

Just place both views in the xml layout, so that the overlap (e.g. for `FrameLayout`, both with width and height as `match_parent`). The last one you add goes on top.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use an `ImageButton` only.

`ImageButton` has a `background` attribute for the background image

and a `src` attribute for the image in the foreground.

*See this existing [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2283993/320111) on StackOverflow.*

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ImageButton01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/album_icon"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use a `RelativeLayout` like matiash said:

Here's an example code for a custom header for a navigation drawer containing your profile facebook picture

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/customHeader"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/green_gradient"/>

<com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView
    android:id="@+id/leftPic"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    facebook:preset_size="small"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

**RESULT**

You can add an ImageButton where you would like, just add the following code into your layout

```
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/myImageButton
android:layout_width="SET YOUR WIDTH"
android:layout_height="SET YOUR HEIGHT"
android:background="ADD YOUR BACKGROUND" />
```