# I want to put image over button

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-xml, android-button

I want to put png image over button i tried android:background but the png takes all the button what i want exactly is to use the logo png over button like this

[image]

the info logo is my png and "about" comes from the button text

Comment: post what you tried..

Comment: An alternative to this is using a RelativeLayout, put ImageView as its child. Now treat this RelativeLayout as a button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

u can use this:

```
android:drawableTop="@drawable/SomeIcon"
```

so then you get this:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/damage"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:text="about"
android:drawableTop="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details"/>
```

[image]

it works for me :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `FrameLayout`. In a `FrameLayout`, the z-index is defined by the order in which the items are added, for example

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_text" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/my_drawable"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

In this instance, the `ImageView` would be drawn on top of the `Button`, along the bottom center of the `Button`.

Answer (score 1):

You can check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283444/android-image-button)
Basically, you can use:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ImageButton01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/album_icon"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button" />
```

As the thread says.

Answer (score 1):

Take a `RelativeLayout`, place `ImageView` inside it. Now set `onClickListener` on RelativeLayout.
By this way you can create more complex buttons.

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/your_btn_id" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
android:drawableTop
```

to put drawable at top of Button and use appropriate padding to make it position well.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Buttton
        android:layout_width="99dp"
        android:layout_height="99dp"
        android:background = "@drawable/bg" />
```

bg is your custom image.